# Using SASS with Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

As we build some bigger projects, I've been thinking about using a CSS pre-processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)  to help manage our CSS resources.  Developing on Salesforce, though, I could see that getting complicated:  All of our static resources are in a zipped Static Resource file (which we typically edit in Eclipse using the [ZipEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipeditor/) plug-in) so we'd need some way to build the scss files into css without adding too much complexity or extra work.  What development tools can help us do this effectively?

Comment: SASS is a command line tool and there not eclipse plugins. Maybe you could stop using ZipEditor, edit your .scss file using aptana or text editor and finally run an script to compile the sass file and zip the result into your zipped static resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use SASS, but we do something similar: run our JS through an optimizer/compiler.

We created a simple Ant script that compiles the JS, puts it in a folder hierarchy for our main JS static resource, zips the static resource file, and re-deploys it (by calling the Force.com Migration Toolkit "deploy" Ant task).

It's a bit of a pain - takes a total of about 30 seconds from editing a JS file to deploying it. Using a good set of developer tools that allow real-time in-browser testing of JS/CSS changes (without deployment) is your friend.